# How to generate all classes under a base package when using WSDL2Java from Axis 2?

Tags: java, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I am trying to force WSDL2Java (`org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java`) to generate all the classes under a given base package, for example com.mycompany.thewebservice.*

According to [the documentation](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/CodegenToolReference.html#cmdref) the -p option should do the trick:

*-p   --package     The target package name. If omitted, a default package (formed using the target namespace of the WSDL) will be used.*

But unfortunately when we use the -p option, only the 3 main classes (XService.java, XCallbackHandler.java and XServiceStub.java) are generated under the given package.  Many other packages are generated like for example:

- com.theservice.*
- org.w3.www._2004._60.xmlmime
- org.xmlsoap.schemas.soap.encoding

This is a mess for us because we integrate many webservices and we want to keep all the classes for a service under a common base folder.

We were using Axis 1 in the past and its WSDL2Java (`org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java`) has a parameter --package that works like a charm.  In this case all the classes are neatly generated under the package that I specify.

Is there a way to force Axis 2 WSDL2Java to generate all the classes under a given package?  I know about the -ns2p --namespace2package parameter, but I don't want to list the URLs one by one for every service that we integrate.

Comment: Reported as an Axis 2 WSDL2Java bug:  https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/AXIS2/issues/AXIS2-5940

Answer (score 0):

I'm using axis2-eclipse-codegen-plugin-1.7.9 and -p option also doesn't place all the generated classes under one package for me.

I have found a workaround for that issue.

1) Simply drop downloaded axis2-eclipse-codegen-plugin-1.7.9.jar file under Eclipse/STS folder named "droppings"
2) restart your Eclipse-based IDE
3) from STS menu go to File --> New --> Other...   , select Axis2 Code Generator (under Axis2 Wizards) --> click on Next --> select "Generate Java source code from a WSDl file" -->  Next --> point to your WSDL file location --> Next --> for Codegen option select custom, fill the other fields --> click on the Advance Options and there
4) **uncheck** the checkbox "Unpacks the databinding classes" like on the screen shot below, it tells Axis2 to generate all the binding classes as inner classes according to [Axis2 CodegenToolReference](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/CodegenToolReference.html) :

> unpackClasses   Unpacks the generated classes. This forces the
>   databinding classes to be generated separately, which otherwise would
>   have been generated as inner classes.

[image: Axis2 Codegen Wizard]